# How to prevent Android from closing Service?

Tags: android, service

FirstActivity starts MyService.
MyService is run as a foreground thing... with that notification icon.
SecondActivity starts.

However, if the user gets rid of SecondActivity, and wishes to continue the application after quite some time (like a few hours or days) and pulls down the notification and clicks on the notification icon, a fatal error occurs.

The thing works if the user gets rid of SecondActivity, and clicks on the notification icon only after a short time.

How to make MyService not close? Or am I missing something?

Comment: How can we help without error log?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are having some different issue here, I would still answer your question related to the services. Kindly post the code and the log that we may help you better.

Preventing [services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) from getting killed by the `android system` is not in your hand, 
If system runs out of resources and your services is not working with the `activity` which is visible to user, `android system` may kill your service.

What can you do in this scenario, request `android framework` to start the `service` as soon as the resources are available in case the `service` was killed.

To do that you need to return [START_REDELIVER_INTENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_REDELIVER_INTENT) from the `onStartCommand()` of the the `service` that it may be recreated.

Kindly check more on this at given link.
 if you are using [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) the service will call `stopSelf()` as soon as the work is done,

So you may want to consider extending [Services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I really appreciate it. Is there any way I can trigger the Android System to kill background apps/services so that I can test and be sure that it works?

Comment: @user3635998, well you can stop the service by your self if you want by calling onStop()

Comment: I want to test if the START_REDELIVER_INTENT value prevents the service from being killed (at least when the user clicks on the icon, it does not show fatal error). So, I want to trigger Android System to kill background apps/services.

Comment: START_REDELIVER_INTENT does not prevent the service from being  killed, it makes sure that the service will be recreated if the android system kills the service